# Using the Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE with Johnny-five

Tags: javascript, johnny-five, adafruit

I am new to small electronics and Javascript but I really want to use Johnny-five.io with my Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE over bluetooth. I can communicate with the board over USB and I understand that the board will not run Node.js so it needs to be connected somehow. A tethered robot is just not so fun. I would like to use bluetooth because AdaFruit provided a very hackable app for the phone.

Can anyone simply get me to the "Hello World" equivalent over bluetooth? It can be from my laptop's bluetooth connection to get started. If I can figure that out, I can figure out the rest of the code.

The board is compatible and I can use it to do the basics. I know that I could tether a Pi or something but that brings up other practical problems.

Comment: http://www.samjulien.com/johnny-feather/ might be worth investigating.

Comment: Yeah - I saw that and he is a real nice guy - I have talked to him on Twitter and gitter. Unfortunately this board is a little different. Thanks!